# VS2013 Automatically comment line of code while build/debug

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, build, comments

I try to find something that could help me but nothing was good so far.

I would like to know if there is any option to comment some lines of code while i start building/debugging?

I don't want to do it manually ("edit and continue" manually isn't a solution). I want "tell VS" to automatically comment specified line of code if i start to build or debug.
I need this line of code when i am testing app at server, but when i do it locally i have to have it commented.
Hope you understand my problem and will give me fast solution, thank you.

I use VS2013 and C#.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: sorry it's C# my mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would [preprocessor directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx) help you? By default the DEBUG directive is enabled for Debug configurations, so any code between `#if(DEBUG)` and `#endif` will only be executed in your Debug configuration.

Comment: I have got 4 configurations where i want to make it commented, so if i want to do it in your way i should try:

`#if (!DEBUG || !DEBUG1 || !DEBUG2 || !DEBUG3) 
variable=5;
#endif`

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
if( !System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached )
{
  //code which should only run if not being debugged
}
```

Otherwise use preprocessor directives as Jenszcz suggests.