# VS2013 - Specific action for a few configs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, build

Here is a question i asked earlier, that can explain what i am looking for:

[The question with help you understand the problem is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670779/vs2013-automatically-comment-line-of-code-while-build-debug/31671769#31671769)

What will be better?

```
#if (!DEBUG || !DEBUG1 || !DEBUG2 || !DEBUG3) 
variable=5; #endif

or

if( !System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached )
{
  //code which should only run if not being debugged
}
```

If I want to attach this specific action to my 4 configs, should i use first option or the second will also be good, because System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached will fit to each of my configs?

Comment: Those two snippets do two different things. The first checks for conditional compilation symbols (by their names I'm guessing your symbols are all in some sort of debug build configuration). The second checks if a debugger is attached. A debugger can be attached to any build configuration.

Looking at your previous question, it seems like System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached would be more appropriate for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I got it. So if i understand you, the debugger option will help solve my problem (to understand it, click the link i attached at the top of my question)?

Comment: Sorry, looks like I misread your previous question. If I understood correctly, you need one behaviour when you're running the app locally, and a different behaviour when the app is deployed on a server. In that case, assuming you're using different build configurations for those two situations, then preprocessor directives would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now all is clear for me.