# VS2013 Change code through flag in config file

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, build, config

Can I edit the config file, and add a flag to it ?

Let me explain. Assume that I use Myconfig file and MyScript.cs file.

In MyScript.cs file I have something like this:

```
bool flag;

...

if(!flag)
{
   variable=5;
}
```

Now my question is: If i can add some line of code to my xml config file to change flag to true when i debug/run app using this config? The purpose is clear: if i change flag to true in this file, specific lines of code won't run. And thats what i am looking for.
Additionally i don't want the client to see this parameter/flag also.

Can i do this that way, and if the answer is yes, how can i do it (what should i add to xml config file)?

To better understand my problem look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672734/vs2013-specific-action-for-a-few-configs/31673162#31673162)

Answer (score 0):

Use "[Application Settings Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx)" then you can access your flag like Settings.Default.YourCustomFlag.